# Why do my "All Time Review Stats" and "Badge Progress" show different numbers in each category?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

My rep only allows me to review the first 2 categories: 'First Posts' and 'Late Answers'. But whenever I go to either of them and check my overall review stats, the numbers shown **don't match**. Here are the screen shots (captured at the same time in 2 different tabs):

### First Posts :

[image: First Post Review Stats]

### Late Answers :

[image: Late Answers Review Stats]

(Even the progress bar at the top shows the these different numbers).

Why is this happening? If the all time is about that category, why the badge progress (which I assume is the overall reviews) is different, too?

Answer (score 4):

First Posts and Late Answers are entirely separate queues; in fact, so are all the others. The six review queues have nothing to do with each other (except 1. sharing an overview screen at /review, and 2. sometimes the same post gets to First Posts and Late Answers). The badges - Custodian, Reviewer, and Steward - are awarded separately for each queue. Because the queues are all separate, badge progress in one queue doesn't affect the others. Basically, they're not the same queue, and have no compulsion to match each other.

**tl;dr** They're not the same statistic, so they don't have to match.

(I don't know of any place that tracks your stats across all the queues - you'll have to do that manually.)